# Haskell rounding numbers to 2 decimals

Tags: haskell

I am trying to round a number to two digits in haskell,
so if the output let's say is 1.98887779, I want it to only outpus 1.98.
note that I already have a function and I want the round to happen around an operation.
thanks

I have tried

```
round $
```

but it's not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to round a number to two digits in Haskell, so if the
> output let's say is 1.98887779, I want it to only outpts 1.98

If you round that number to two decimal places, it should end up with 1.99.

The way to round a number `x` to a given number of decimal places `n` is to:

- multiply x by 10 raised to the power of `n`
- round this value
- divided it by 10 raised to the power of `n`

Thus:

```
tenPow :: Integer -> Float
tenPow n = 10.0 ^ n

roundN :: Float -> Integer -> Float
roundN x n = (fromIntegral . round)  (x * tenPow n) / tenPow n
```

The `round` function is a little bit odd if you approach it from a non-mathematical point-of-view.

I would expect:

- 3.5 -> 4
- 4.3 -> 4
- 4.5 -> 5
- 4.8 -> 5

But Haskell, for good mathematical reasons, does this:

- 3.5 -> 4
- 4.3 -> 4
- 4.5 -> 4
- 4.8 -> 5

That is so `round(3.5 + 4.5)` = `round 3.5` + `round 4.5`.

https://typeclasses.com/featured/rounding